# sqoop with sql server retrieving more records

Tags: sqoop

Q: I want to import 5000 rows from **SQL server using SQOOP** but its giving me 20000 rows. I am using below query.

```
sudo -E -u hdfs sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://hostname;username=*****;password=*****;database=*****" --driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver --query "select top 5000 * from Tb_Emp  where \$CONDITIONS" --split-by EmpID -m 4 --target-dir /home/sqoop_SQLServeroutput
```

retrieved 20000 records

every mapper is getting 5000 records. but if i do this on **mysql** then it gives 5000 records as expected.

```
sudo -E -u hdfs sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://hostname/<database_name> --username **** --password **** --query 'select * from Tb_Emp where $CONDITIONS limit 5000' --split-by EmpID -m 4 --target-dir /home/sqoop_MySqloutput
```

retrieved 5000 records.

don't why its happening.

Answer (score 0):

Using the "top x" or "limit x" clauses do not make much sense with Sqoop as it can return different values on each query execution (there is no "order by"). Also in addition the clause will very likely confuse split generation, ending with not that easily deterministic outputs. Having said that I would recommend you to use only 1 mapper (-m 1 or --num-mappers 1) in case that you need to import predefined number of rows. Another solution would be to create temporary table with the required data on the MySQL/SQL Server side and import this whole temp table with Sqoop.

Comment: i used 5000 just for testing,my actual data in SQL table is more than 100 million rows. using only 1 mapper will not work for me. And why its giving correct output in case of mysql.